# Can I use VS code on Ipad

Tags: ipad

I’am a student who currently studying Electrical Engineering. One of my major is about coding, and my lecturer suggest VS code, and I used it on uni computer, the problem is, I only have an Ipad with me, and I want to do code when i’am not at uni, can i used vs code website version to do full code, or is there any apps that can do remote coding or any apps based on vs code that i can used on ipad?

I’m already trying the vs code website ver, but when i want to download extension, it say limited feature, i’m expecting i can used vs code website the same like i used on uni computer

Comment: Yep, this pretty much sums up the current state of affairs re iPad as programming platform: It is simply nowhere near as well-suited for programming than a desktop/laptop computer is. Sure, you’ve got https://vscode.dev, [Playgrounds](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/swift-playgrounds/id908519492), or perhaps you can remote into a proper computer, but it’s not the same thing as a rich and robust desktop IDE. IMHO, the “download extension” limitation is the least of your issues.